# Custom Telegram Clients: How is their distribution possible if `api_id` and `api_hash` are intended to be secret?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I can't understand a fundamental thing regarding the possibility of distributing unofficial (custom) clients for Telegram.

For their startup, the `api_id` and `api_hash` tokens are required, and on the official Telegram website on the page for obtaining them, it is clearly stated, "It is forbidden to pass this value to third parties".

The same is said on the `telethon` page, a library which I am primarily interested in: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/signing-in.html (although the question is not about the library, but about the Telegram protocol in general)

I read this useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61662775/5400264 , but the key point in it only confirms my doubts:
"... when you publish your application, anyone can sign in without needing to provide their api_id and api_hash. Of course, you would need to keep those secret to try to minimize people from using your key in their applications, although this is not really doable"

I see in several places in the public domain `api_id` and `api_hash` of some custom clients:
https://github.com/vysheng/tg/blob/6547c0b21b977b327b3c5e8142963f4bc246187a/loop.h#L21-L22

As well as the `api_id` and `api_hash` of official clients:
https://blb.team/threads/app-hash-app-id-oficialnyx-klientov.294/

So:

1. If `api_id` and `api_hash` can't be shared and every user of a custom client must obtain their own, this is a) inconvenient; b) pointless since the user enters their phone number and password when logging into the custom client anyway.
2. If `api_id` and `api_hash` can be shared, then a) why does the official site prohibit doing this; b) clearly, this data will be used by spammers, leading to the developer's account being blocked.

---

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something from the start? Can anyone shed light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

These values are meant to be kept secret. So one shouldn't publish them in public forums online, and one shouldn't use leaked values that are not their own.

`api_id` and `api_hash` *shouldn't* be shared. For example, Telegram for Android is a binary that has the official values embedded. Millions of users use these when they use Telegram for Android. They don't each sign up for a developer account.

With enough dedication, you can of course extract these values from the binary. This doesn't mean you should, as Telegram might have a way to detect misuse and ban the account.

> clearly, this data will be used by spammers, leading to the developer's account being blocked

This is up to Telegram to determine. If you don't feel safe distributing your application with the API ID and hash, you will need to find alternative methods.